Closed formula for the factorial over naturals

How to prove that there is no formula for $n!$ that does only use the binary operations $+,-,*,/$ on natural numbers, powers of natural numbers, and fixed natural numbers?

The same question over the reals is asked here. Similar questions have been asked several times on math.SE but none of the answers there provides a formula of the specified type.
I am quite sure that there is no such formula but I have no clue how one could prove that.
Update. As you can see below, I was wrong, there is such a formula for the factorial. In fact, as was communicated to me by the  second author, a solution to exactly this problem has been found before, see this recent paper for some history.
Older stuff. In particular, I do not allow integer parts (floors or ceilings), except that the division function returns the integral quotient, so it does hide a sort of floor operation, which is allowed in this form.
I do not allow integrals or derivatives, sum or product symbols, I do not allow substitutions into functions with multiple variables etc. The length of the formula should be uniformly bounded for all $n$ (otherwise $1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot n$ would work).
My motivation is that my 9-year-old son asked me this question. This doesn't mean that your solution should be understandable by a 9-year-old, but rather that I only allow the operations that he has heard of. Also note that most likely there is no such formula but I want a proof for that.

I think you need to be very precise with your question for it to have a meaningful answer. You write "I am interested in the existence of a closed formula that uses only the four basic operations and exponential powers" but it is unclear why the definitional formula $n! = \prod_{j=1}^{n} j$ does not qualify according to this "definition."

Because it uses the product symbol. I think I was quite precise.

If you don't allow the use of constants such as $\pi$ and $e$ then I think you could attempt to argue that no such closed formula can have the correct asymptotics as given by Stirling's formula.

I agree with you all, as I wrote, I also don't expect that a closed formula would exist. What I want is a proof that it doesn't exist.

I still don't completely understand what class of sequences you are trying to define, but maybe it is the same as those with rational generating functions (in other words, those satisfying a linear recurrence with constant coefficients)?

is differentiation allowed? $n!=\frac{d^n x^n}{dx^n}$

It’s not clear to me whether you consider the basic operations on reals or on natural numbers. In the latter case, i.e., if the allowed operations are $n+m$, $n\cdot m$, $n\mathbin{\dot{\smash-}}m$, $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$, $n^m$ for $n,m\in\mathbb N$, there does exist such a closed formula for $n!$; in fact, such a closed formula exists for every Kalmár elementary function. This is apparently proved in Mazzanti, Plain bases for classes of primitive recursive functions, but I can’t access the paper at the moment.

I suppose your set $S$ is the minimal set of $f:\mathbb N\to k$ such that: i. Every constant function is in $S$. ii. $f(n)=n$ is in $S$. iii. If $f,g\in S$, then any of $f+g$, $-f$, $fg$, $1/f$, $f^g$ is in $S$ whenever well-defined for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
In my opinion, the main issue with the question is that you haven't specified $k$. Namely, if $k=\mathbb C$, then $\exp(2\pi in/m)$ is periodic modulo $m$, so, by some geometric series, one concludes that $f-g[f/g]$ is in $S$ for $f,g\in S$, and then so is $n!$ by https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4605121/#comment9702994_4605121

Factorial grows faster than any polynomial in $n$ and faster than any exponential with constant base, so any closed form will need to involve something like $n^n$. But then it grows too fast. (I know that this is not a proof, just thinking out loud.)

I have made a big edit (please revert if you don't approve) that I think will prevent further misunderstandings, downvotes, and close votes.

@te4 From the context it is absolutely clear that no complex numbers are allowed. I also made this clear in my edit now, I think the OP will agree. The OP wants a formula suitable for a 9-old (or rather a proof that such a formula doesn't exist).

@MartinBrandenburg Is this really so clear from what the OP wrote? The sentence of the first link in their post says "I know that the Fibonacci sequence can be described via the Binet's formula." Of course, that formula uses constants other than natural numbers. So if the point is to show that $n!$ does not have a formula like the one for Fibonacci numbers, your interpretation might be too narrow.

@SamHopkins That's a question from a different user from 2010. And the OP made clear that all these interpretations of formulas don't fit.

@SamHopkins in an earlier comment you mentioned rational generating functions, but they don't cover $n^n$ for example (which is allowed).

@EmilJeřábek You mention a paper about recursive functions. $n!$ can be evaluated as $f(n,1)$ where $f(n,r)$ is defined recursively as $f(n,r)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
f(n-1,n r) & n>1 \
r & \text{n=1} \
\end{array}\right.$.

You reject the simple product representation $n! = \prod_{i=1}^{n} i$ which is generally considered to be closed form because it consists of a finite number of multiplication operations. If you're not allowing loop structures or tests on variables, this would also seem to prohibit sum or nested sum representations. You don't allow substitutions into functions with multiple variables. You can probably add enough restrictions to prohibit a solution, but the question seems rather artificial to me.

Does this answer your question? Proof that the factorial is nonelementary and Expanded concept of elementary function?

@StevenClark I’m not sure you understand what I wrote. The class of Kalmár elementary functions does allow bounded recursion, bounded sums, and products, hence it trivially contains $n!$. By results of the paper I mentioned, any such function can be constructed without recursion using just composition of basic integer functions $n+m$, $n\cdot m$, $n\mathbin{\dot{\smash-}}m$, $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$, $2^n$ (and even some of its subsets). This is a highly nontrivial result, and answers the question if the $-$ and $/$ operations are intended to be interpreted as the operations on $\mathbb N$.

Though for $n!$, one does not need the general result; the simple explicit construction in Akiva Weinberger’s comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605121/is-factorial-considered-a-closed-formula#comment9702994_4605121) mentioned above by te4 does the job.

@Emil You are right, over $\mathbb N$ where division is defined as $\lfloor a/b\rfloor$, that is a perfect solution.

Bad news, my son said that he doesn't allow division over $\mathbb N$... The formula should work over $\mathbb R$. Should I make a fork and create different questions for the two variants?

Given the amount of attention the question already received, I think it’s better to keep it as one question, while specifying that it has two variants.

A fun fact: you can express factorial in umbral calculus using exponentiation and evaluation operation (finding standard part): $\Gamma(x)=\text{eval }\left(\frac{(B+x)^{B+x}}{ e^{B+x}}\right)$

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394130/2513

@Anixx I already linked to that math.SE question in my comment.

@TimothyChow I think that possibly this answer is even more fitting: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1424027/2513

I am confused: your comment says "Bad news, my son said that he doesn't allow division over $\mathbb N$", but your later edit says "In particular, I do not allow integer parts (floors or ceilings), except that the division function returns the integral quotient, so it does hide a sort of floor operation, which is allowed in this form."  Am I misinterpreting, or are these in conflict?  Which one should govern?

@LSpice These are indeed in conflict. I posted another version of the problem at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484129 and for the reason of the conflict see the comments under Emil's answer.

"using powers of natural numbers": why don't you consider the power operation among other binary operations?

Factorial does have a closed formula using integer division $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$ due to J. Robinson [1]: we have
$$\begin{align*}
n\bmod m&=n-m\lfloor n/m\rfloor,\\
\binom rn&=\left\lfloor\frac{(2^r+1)^r}{2^{rn}}\right\rfloor\bmod 2^r,\\
n!&=\textstyle\left\lfloor2^{n^3}\big/\binom{2^{n^2}}n\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor n^{n^2}\big/\binom{n^n}n\right\rfloor.
\end{align*}$$
(That is1, $n!=\bigl\lfloor r^n/\binom rn\bigr\rfloor$ for any $r>(2n)^{n+1}$, as the bound is stated in [1]. It actually holds2 already for $r\ge n!\,n^2/2$, which implies3 the second given expression for $n!$.)
In fact, the class of functions $\mathbb N^k\to\mathbb N$ that have a closed expression using $n+m$, $n\mathbin{\dot-}m$, $n\cdot m$, $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$, and $n^m$ (or even just $2^n$) is quite vast: it coincides with the class of Kalmár elementary functions aka elementary recursive functions. This was proved by Mazzanti [2,§4].
References
[1] Julia Robinson: Existential definability in arithmetic, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 72 (1952), no. 3, pp. 437–449, doi 10.2307/1990711.
[2] Stefano Mazzanti: Plain bases for classes of primitive recursive functions, Mathematical Logic Quarterly 48 (2002), no. 1, pp. 93–104, doi 10.1002/1521-3870(200201)48:1%3C93::AID-MALQ93%3E3.0.CO;2-8.
Footnotes

To see that the expression $n!=\bigl\lfloor2^{n^3}/\binom{2^{n^2}}n\bigr\rfloor$ follows from Robinson’s formula, recall that $2^n\ge n+1$ for all integers $n$, thus we have $2^{n-1}=4\cdot2^{n-3}\ge4(n-2)\ge2n$ if $n\ge4$, whence $2^{n^2}>2^{n^2-1}\ge(2n)^{n+1}$; one can check that the expression is valid for $n=0,\dots,3$ by hand. Alternatively, since $n^n\le2^{n^2}$, this expression for $n!$ follows from the other one, proved below.

Since $r^n/\binom rn=n!\prod_{i<n}(1-i/r)^{-1}$, we see that $n!=\bigl\lfloor r^n/\binom rn\bigr\rfloor$ holds iff
$$\tag{$*$}\prod_{i<n}\left(1-\frac ir\right)^{-1}<1+\frac1{n!}.$$
The power series expansion for $\exp\bigl(-\sum_{i<k}\log(1-i/r)\bigr)$ shows that the LHS in $(*)$ is $1+n(n-1)/(2r)+O(n^4/r^2)$, whence the minimal $r$ that satisfies $(*)$ is asymptotically $$\frac{n!\,n(n-1)}2+O(n^2).$$
Let me show instead that the bound
$$r\ge\frac{n!\,n^2}2$$
implies $(*)$ for all $n\ge0$. One can check the cases $n=0,1,2$ separately, hence we may assume $n\ge3$. Then $r\ge n!\,n^2/2>n^2(n-1)$, which implies
$$1-\frac ir=\frac{r-i}r>\frac{2r+i^2}{2r+(i+1)^2}=\frac{1+i^2/(2r)}{1+(i+1)^2/(2r)}$$
for all $i<n$, as
$$\begin{align*}
(r-i)\bigl(2r+(i+1)^2\bigr)&=2r^3+ri^2+r-i(i+1)^2\\
&\ge2r^3+ri^2+r-(n-1)n^2\\
&>2r^3+ri^2=r(2r+i^2).
\end{align*}$$
Thus,
$$\prod_{i<n}\left(1-\frac ir\right)^{-1}<\prod_{i<n}\frac{1+(i+1)^2/(2r)}{1+i^2/(2r)}=1+\frac{n^2}{2r}\le1+\frac1{n!}.$$

We have $n!\le2n^{n-2}$ for all $n\ge3$: it holds for $n=3$, and then we proceed by induction in the obvious way. Thus, $n^n\ge n!\,n^2/2$ for $n\ge3$, whence $n!=\bigl\lfloor n^{n^2}/\binom{n^n}n\bigr\rfloor$ by footnote 2. This formula also holds for $n=0,1,2$ by direct calculation.



There is a fun exercise in Knuth's Art of Computer Programming: Suppose you have a computer which can compute any arithmetic operation in time $O(1)$, no matter how large the inputs are. Show that it can factor $N$ in time polynomial in $\log N$.

The idea is that the Euclidean algorithm to compute $\text{GCD}(M, N)$ runs in time $O(\min(\log M, \log N))$ in this model, and you can compute $k!$ in time polynomial in $\log k$ using the formulas in this answer, so you can do a binary search to find $k$ with $1< \text{GCD}(N, k!) <N$.

The ambiguity comes from the fact that when I originally posted the question, I explicitly wrote that only the four basic operations plus exponentials were allowed, having the reals in mind, but later it was edited by Martin Brandenburg, who rewrote the question to clarify it and added that it was about $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ functions. As I also didn't know the answer for this problem and I was late to notice the change, I thought I would leave it like that. I'll post a separate question about $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ functions.

@domotorp your question can be formulated in shorter way: a proof that factorial is not an elementary function.

@Anixx That just begs the question “what is an elementary function”, hence all the ambiguity.

@EmilJeřábek I think, elementary function is quite estrablished concept (a function that can be constructed using the field operations, exponentiation and logarithm).

@Anixx For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function also lists trigonometric functions and their inverses, which are not definable from field operations, exp, and log over the reals.

@EmilJeřábek of course, over the complex numbers.

But the question is over the reals, not complex numbers. Also, the question does not allow logarithm.

@EmilJeřábek if it is not an elementary function, then it cannot be expressed even with logarithm. So without logarithm it cannot be expressed as well.

The question did seem like a bit of a moving target, but after thinking about it some more I believe the intent was prove there are no simple solutions analogous to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k=\frac{ n, (n+1)}{2}$.

Adding the greatest integer to the possible functions used seems to me a reasonable approach.  That is something that can be understood by a 9-year-old.

He will be definitely impressed by $\left\lfloor\frac{2^{n^3}}{\binom{2^{n^2}}n}\right\rfloor$ :)

You credited it in a comment on the main post, and I'll just add in a comment here that this formula was also mentioned by @‍AkivaWeinberger in a comment on Is factorial considered a closed formula? (originally linked here, as you point out, in a comment by @te4).

@DavidESpeyer Very cool! Thanks for sharing!

$$
n!=q\left(2^{n^{3}},q\left(\left(2^{2^{n^{2}}}+1\right)^{2^{n^{2}}},2^{n2^{n^{2}}}\right)-2^{2^{n^{2}}}q\left(q\left(\left(2^{2^{n^{2}}}+1\right)^{2^{n^{2}}},2^{n2^{n^{2}}}\right), 2^{2^{n^{2}}}\right)\right)
$$
$$
q(x,y)=\lfloor x/y \rfloor
$$   Just to serve as a joke actually.

@LSpice The formula is actually due to Robinson, as credited in the answer.

@EmilJeřábek A minor detail:
$r = 2^{n^2} > (2n)^{n+1}$ does not hold for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.
For example at $n=1$, we have $r = 2^{1^2} = 2 \not> (2 \cdot 1)^{1+1} = 4 $.
If basing on J. Robinson's result, one should use instead $r = 2^{3n^2}$. However, your formula seems valid empirically.

It is easy to show that $2^{n^2}>(2n)^{n+1}$ holds for all $n≥4$, and it's trivial to check that the formula holds for $n=0,…,3$ by hand. Anyway, to be honest, I don't see where Robinson got the expression $(2n)^{n+1}$ in the first place, and I do not think it has much significance. The bound that's really needed is $\prod_{i<n}(1−i/r)^{−1}<1+1/n!$, and for $r$ much larger than $n$, the LHS here is $1+n(n−1)/(2r)+O(n^4/r^2)$. Hence we just need $r$ larger than about $n!n(n−1)/2$, possibly with a few small exceptions that should be easy to quantify.

I really like this answer and will be coming back to it, so for my own benefit let me spell out my understanding of it. By the binomial theorem, for $a$ large, the digits of $x=(1+a)^r$ in base $a$ are precisely the binomial coefficients $\binom rn$, extracted by $\lfloor x/a^n\rfloor\text{ mod }a$. Then $r^n/\binom rn=n!\prod_{1\leq i\leq r}(1+\frac{i-1}{r-i+1})>n!$ converges to $n!$ as $r$ diverges. Taking $a$ and $r$ large enough gives your formulas.

@EmilJeřábek Yes, initially I thought your formula was incorrect since it did not adhere to the bounds set by Robinson. However, I edited my post after testing it. It is indeed easy to prove.

I included the derivation in the answer itself for good measure.
