Closed formula for the factorial over reals

How to prove that there is no formula for $n!$ that does only use the binary operations $+,-,*,/$ on real numbers, powers of real numbers, and fixed real numbers?

Similar question have been asked several times on math.SE but none of the answers there provide a formula of the specified type. The same question over the naturals (where the result of division is a quotient) surprisingly has a positive solution.
I am quite sure that there is no such formula but I have no clue how one could prove that.
In particular, I do not allow integer parts (floors or ceilings), I do not allow integrals or derivatives, sum or product symbols, I do not allow substitutions into functions with multiple variables etc. The length of the formula should be uniformly bounded for all $n$ (otherwise $1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot n$ would work).
My motivation is that my 9-year-old son asked me this question. This doesn't mean that your solution should be understandable by a 9-year-old, but rather that I only allow the operations that he has heard of. Also note that most likely there is no such formula but I want a proof for that.

Are we allowed to use rationals in exponential? for example $(n^{1/2})^{(1/2)^n}$? Also allowing arbitrary real numbers sounds to me like a bad idea - if there is a solution is likely to be with rather contrived real numbers and if there isn't it will be harder to prove. After all Mills' constant sounds amazing until you read how it is defined. @fe4's variant formalization with $k=\mathbb R$ captures this variant.

Rationals are surely allowed in the exponent and I think contrived reals are welcome too, but of course I'm happy to see solutions to other variants as well.

Is something like $(-1)^{\frac12} = i$ forbidden?

By default, yes, but I'm happy to see a solution to any variant of the problem.

Well in that case, it was mentioned in a comment to your previous question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484083/closed-formula-for-the-factorial-over-naturals#comment1260812_484083) that if you allow complex numbers there again is a formula for factorial.

@Sam I unfortunately don't fully understand te4's comment. How do you convert a number like $exp(2\pi i n/m)$ back to $n/m$?

Assuming you don't allow arbitrary constants for now, you can obtain $e$ as the limit of $(1 + \frac1n)^n$, so the $\left(\frac ne\right)^n$ part of the growth rate is attainable, but can you obtain $\pi$ for the $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ part?

I'm going to answer a stronger version of a specific interpretation of your question, but I think that this is indicative of how hard it's going to be to define $n!$ using more 'basic' operations without doing something that feels like cheating by sneaking the natural numbers in (e.g., something like a floor function or $\cos(x)$).
The key idea is the notion of o-minimality of an expansion of $\mathbb{R}$. A first-order structure extending $(\mathbb{R},<,+,\cdot)$ is o-minimal if every definable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite union of intervals (of possibly zero or infinite length). This has extremely strong structural consequences, although by itself doesn't rule out being able to define $n!$ (as there are o-minimal expansions of $\mathbb{R}$ in which the restriction of $\Gamma(x)$ to $(0,\infty)$ is definable). In order to show that we can't do this, we need to use some more specific work of van den Dries, Macintyre, and Marker on definability in the structure $\mathcal{R}_{\exp} = (\mathbb{R},<,+,\cdot,e^x)$, which is o-minimal by Wilkie's theorem (a kind of generalization of the Tarski–Seidenberg theorem).

Proposition. There is no partial function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ first-order definable with parameters in the structure $\mathcal{R}_{\exp} = (\mathbb{R},<,+,\cdot,e^x)$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n) = n!$.


Before the proof though, I want to give a little indication of how this class of functions is fairly broad (but also limited in other ways). Any function you can build out of polynomials, rational functions, and $e^x$ is first-order definable in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$. Since local inverses of definable functions are definable, we also have that $\log x$, $\sqrt[n]{x}$, and any functions built out of them are covered. These functions also don't need to be analytic. $\max\{x,y\}$, $\min\{x,y\}$, and $|x|$ are all included, as are step functions of intervals. For any function $f(x)$ definable in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$, $f'(x)$ is as well (as a partial function). Likewise if $f(x,y)$ is definable, then $\sup_y f(x,y)$ and $\inf_y f(x,y)$ are too (fixing some reasonable convention for handing infinite suprema and infima). And again, remember that all of these things can be combined, which means that expressions such as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\log\log\log\log\log (19+x^{5040})}{\max\{\pi+e,x^{\pi^\pi}\}+\sqrt{x^\pi + \pi^x}}e^{(\log|x|)^2 \chi_{[2,5)\cup(17,\infty)}\left(x^2+\sup_z\inf_y\frac{y^{19}-2}{|z+e^x|}\right)}
$$
(where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$) give functions that are definable (with parameters) in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$.
Notably though, nothing like the floor function or $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ is definable in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$. This is because these things would allow you to define the integers and once the integers are present the complexity of first-order definability explodes massively. In fact every Borel function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (and more) is first-order definable with parameters in $\mathcal{R}_{\cos}=(\mathbb{R},<,+,\cdot,\cos(x))$. The drastic contrast between definability in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$ and $\mathcal{R}_{\cos}$ is one of my favorite examples of what I find so interesting about mathematical logic.

Proof of proposition
Let $g(x) = f(x+1) - (x+1)f(x)$. We have that $g(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, by o-minimality, it must be the case that $g(x) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $x$ (since a definable function in an o-minimal structure can only change sign (in the sense of positive, negative, or zero) finitely many times. Therefore $f(x)$ satisfies the recurrence relation $f(x+1) = (x+1)f(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Let $k > -1$ be a natural number such that this holds for all $x \geq k$.
Since there are only finitely many intervals of the form $[n,n+1]$ in $[-1,k]$, we can definably extend the restriction of $f(x)$ to $[k,\infty)$ to a function $f^\ast(x)$ on all of $(-1,\infty)$ satisfying the recurrence relation $f^\ast(x+1) = (x+1)f^\ast(x)$. Note that in particular we must have that $f^\ast(0) = 1$, since $f(k) = f^\ast(k) = k!$.
Since $\log x$ is definable in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$, we have that $h(x) = \log(f^\ast(x))$ is also a definable function. Definable functions in o-minimal structures are differentiable at all but finitely many points and moreover have definable derivatives. Therefore it must be the case that $h(x)$ is eventually convex (since its second derivative must eventually be positive). Therefore $f^\ast(x)$ is eventually log-convex. This is sufficient for the Bohr–Mollerup theorem,* so we must have $f^\ast(x) = \Gamma(x+1)$ for all $x > -1$.
Finally, we have that $\Gamma(x)$ is definable in $\mathcal{R}_{\mathrm{exp}}$, but it was shown in Logarithmic-Exponential Power Series by van den Dries, Macintyre, and Marker that $\Gamma(x)$ is not definable in $\mathcal{R}_{\exp}$. Therefore no such $f(x)$ can exist. $\square$
*The Bohr–Mollerup theorem is not usually stated this way, but it is easy to adapt the proof of it to show that any eventually log-convex function $g : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x+1) = xg(x)$ for all $x>0$ and $g(1) = 1$ is $\Gamma(x)$.
